# UIScrollView is not scrolling with UILabel

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

My hierarchy view and constraints as following image, I set text for UILabel in  viewDidLoad. But only part of text is displayed and can't scroll. 
Do you have any idea?

### [[image: hierarchy view[1]]

### [image: ScrollView Contraints]

### [image: contentView Contraints]

[image: UILabel Contraints]

Comment: Can you show some of the code you use to set up your scrollView?

Comment: override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        self.scrollView.contentSize = self.receiptLabelView.boundingSize
        self.scrollView.flashScrollIndicators()
    }

Comment: @Sarcoma you means my scroll content wrapper constraints is wrong?

Comment: I only want to set very long text and is scrollable in scroll view. But scrollView don't work.

Comment: Don't add height constraint to your label, or it will not fit the text inside

Comment: @Sarcoma I see, but I expect UILabel have dynamic height. But it didn't display all my text.

Comment: I think without the a bottom constraint the contentView will not know it needs to expand it's height.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by remove 2 constraints: 
1. align center x 
2. align center y 
from ScrollViewContentWrapper, and add constraints width equal.